# Connector class from JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, connector

I'm learning about JDBC and I have learned the steps: open connection, execute statement, get result, etc. I know about `Connection`, `Statement`s and the other interfaces, but I just found a tutorial with another class, the `Connector` class. And I don't understand what exactly we can do with this `Connector` class. I have made some app without this class and I don't understand why do I need the `Connector` class? Any feedback will be apreciated!

Here is the code:

```
public Set getAllUsers() {

    Connector connector = new Connector();

    Connection connection = connector.getConnection();

    try {

        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user");

        Set users = new HashSet();

        while(rs.next())

        {

            User user = extractUserFromResultSet(rs);

            users.add(user);

        }

        return users;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

UPDATE:

This is the link where you can find the entire code: https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-data-access-layer-using-jdbc

Comment: Seems that `Connector` is a class created on that tutorial that handles the way to create a database connection. This is a good practice since you want to abstract how you'll get a database connection.

Comment: There is no `Connector` class in JDBC. Link to the article about this Connector class. Look at the code’s `import` statements to get it’s fully-qualified class name.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'd argue it is a bad practice, given the JDBC api already has a feature for that: `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and in that method you can abstract how you handle the `DataSource`: from JNDI, from a library like HikariCP or c3p0, creating your own...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You could still make it a data source that proxies to another data source. But to be honest, that sounds like a poor-man's DI.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and have this `Connector` class as a bridge for it. For me, it shouldn't be a class but an interface as well. Anyway, there are plenty of options to handle this scenario.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I suggest you write that as an Answer.

Comment: Word of warning: your code seems to be leaking connections, statements and result sets. Learn about [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel in fact seems like a tutorial using Java 1.4. It's not even using generics.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have no idea which tutorial is being used, but given the code shown, it can't be very high quality.

Comment: I just added the link to the article

Comment: That article has a lot of red flags of incorrect or dubious usage of JDBC (calling `DriverManager.registerDriver` from application code, not closing resources like connections, etc). You may want to consider following a different tutorial. In any case, that article never defines the `Connector` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Connector` is **probably** a class with a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

> the **factory method pattern** is a creational pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created.

Basically it is a utility class to create a `Connection` hiding the complexity of connection creation.

Comment: I suggest mentioning “probably” since we really don’t know what this `Connector` is about, we can only speculate.